# Why does "conda upgrade" behave differently on a cloned environment?

Tags: python, keras, clone, conda

Using conda on Linux, I wanted to update keras, so I typed `conda upgrade -c conda-forge keras`, and got a huge Package Plan that included

> keras                            pkgs/main::keras-2.2.4-0 --> conda-forge::keras-2.3.1-py37_0

I got nervous about making a huge change to my Python environment, so I said no the "Proceed" prompt. Then I cloned the environment, activated the clone, and again typed `conda upgrade -c conda-forge keras`. This time a got a much shorter Package Plan that included

> keras                            pkgs/main::keras-2.2.4-0 --> conda-forge::keras-2.2.4-py37_1

I'm confused. Is the cloned environment different from the environment it's cloned from? If not, why does `conda upgrade` give a different result?

The complete inputs and outputs are below:

```
(myenv) [myname@ourserver ~]$ conda upgrade -c conda-forge keras
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv

  added / updated specs:
    - keras


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _libgcc_mutex-0.1          |             main           2 KB  conda-forge
    absl-py-0.8.1              |           py37_0         158 KB  conda-forge
    astor-0.7.1                |             py_0          22 KB  conda-forge
    attrs-19.3.0               |             py_0          35 KB  conda-forge
    backcall-0.1.0             |             py_0          13 KB  conda-forge
    binutils_impl_linux-64-2.33.1|       he1b5a44_7         8.6 MB  conda-forge
    binutils_linux-64-2.33.1   |      h9595d00_15          21 KB  conda-forge
    bleach-3.1.0               |             py_0         110 KB  conda-forge
    bzip2-1.0.8                |       h516909a_2         396 KB  conda-forge
    c-ares-1.15.0              |    h516909a_1001         100 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2019.11.28 |       hecc5488_0         145 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py37_0         148 KB  conda-forge
    cycler-0.10.0              |             py_2           9 KB  conda-forge
    dbus-1.13.6                |       he372182_0         602 KB  conda-forge
    decorator-4.4.1            |             py_0          11 KB  conda-forge
    defusedxml-0.6.0           |             py_0          22 KB  conda-forge
    entrypoints-0.3            |        py37_1000          11 KB  conda-forge
    expat-2.2.5                |    he1b5a44_1004         191 KB  conda-forge
    fontconfig-2.13.1          |    he4413a7_1000         327 KB  conda-forge
    freetype-2.10.0            |       he983fc9_1         884 KB  conda-forge
    gast-0.3.2                 |             py_0          11 KB  conda-forge
    gcc_impl_linux-64-7.3.0    |       habb00fd_2        70.5 MB  conda-forge
    gcc_linux-64-7.3.0         |      h553295d_15          22 KB  conda-forge
    gettext-0.19.8.1           |    hc5be6a0_1002         3.6 MB  conda-forge
    glib-2.58.3                |py37h6f030ca_1002         3.3 MB  conda-forge
    grpcio-1.23.0              |   py37he9ae1f9_0         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    gst-plugins-base-1.14.5    |       h0935bb2_0         6.8 MB  conda-forge
    gstreamer-1.14.5           |       h36ae1b5_0         4.5 MB  conda-forge
    gxx_impl_linux-64-7.3.0    |       hdf63c60_2        19.1 MB  conda-forge
    gxx_linux-64-7.3.0         |      h553295d_15          21 KB  conda-forge
    h5py-2.10.0                |nompi_py37h513d04c_100         1.2 MB  conda-forge
    hdf5-1.10.5                |nompi_h3c11f04_1104         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    icu-58.2                   |    hf484d3e_1000        22.6 MB  conda-forge
    importlib_metadata-1.2.0   |           py37_0          40 KB  conda-forge
    ipykernel-5.1.3            |   py37h5ca1d4c_0         160 KB  conda-forge
    ipython-7.10.1             |   py37h5ca1d4c_0         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    ipython_genutils-0.2.0     |             py_1          21 KB  conda-forge
    ipywidgets-7.5.1           |             py_0         101 KB  conda-forge
    jedi-0.15.1                |           py37_0         718 KB  conda-forge
    jinja2-2.10.3              |             py_0          91 KB  conda-forge
    joblib-0.14.0              |             py_0         197 KB  conda-forge
    jpeg-9c                    |    h14c3975_1001         251 KB  conda-forge
    jsonschema-3.2.0           |           py37_0          89 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_client-5.3.3       |           py37_1         132 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_console-6.0.0      |             py_0          19 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_core-4.6.1         |           py37_0          70 KB  conda-forge
    keras-2.3.1                |           py37_0         591 KB  conda-forge
    keras-applications-1.0.8   |             py_1          30 KB  conda-forge
    keras-preprocessing-1.1.0  |             py_0          33 KB  conda-forge
    kiwisolver-1.1.0           |   py37hc9558a2_0          86 KB  conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1    |       h53a641e_7         653 KB  conda-forge
    libffi-3.2.1               |    he1b5a44_1006          46 KB  conda-forge
    libgcc-ng-9.2.0            |       hdf63c60_0         8.6 MB  conda-forge
    libgfortran-ng-7.3.0       |       hdf63c60_2         1.7 MB  conda-forge
    libgpuarray-0.7.6          |    h14c3975_1003         263 KB  conda-forge
    libiconv-1.15              |    h516909a_1005         2.0 MB  conda-forge
    libpng-1.6.37              |       hed695b0_0         343 KB  conda-forge
    libprotobuf-3.11.1         |       h8b12597_0         4.8 MB  conda-forge
    libsodium-1.0.17           |       h516909a_0         330 KB  conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0         |       hdf63c60_0         4.5 MB  conda-forge
    libuuid-2.32.1             |    h14c3975_1000          26 KB  conda-forge
    libxcb-1.13                |    h14c3975_1002         396 KB  conda-forge
    libxml2-2.9.9              |       h13577e0_2         1.3 MB  conda-forge
    mako-1.1.0                 |             py_0          57 KB  conda-forge
    markdown-3.1.1             |             py_0          60 KB  conda-forge
    markupsafe-1.1.1           |   py37h516909a_0          26 KB  conda-forge
    mistune-0.8.4              |py37h516909a_1000          53 KB  conda-forge
    mkl-service-2.3.0          |   py37h516909a_0          64 KB  conda-forge
    mkl_fft-1.0.15             |   py37h516909a_1         169 KB  conda-forge
    mkl_random-1.1.0           |   py37hb3f55d8_0         372 KB  conda-forge
    mock-3.0.5                 |           py37_0          44 KB  conda-forge
    more-itertools-8.0.2       |             py_0          33 KB  conda-forge
    nbconvert-5.6.1            |           py37_0         487 KB  conda-forge
    nbformat-4.4.0             |             py_1          91 KB  conda-forge
    ncurses-6.1                |    hf484d3e_1002         1.3 MB  conda-forge
    notebook-6.0.1             |           py37_0         6.0 MB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.1.1d             |       h516909a_0         2.1 MB  conda-forge
    pandoc-2.8.1               |                0        16.5 MB  conda-forge
    pandocfilters-1.4.2        |             py_1           9 KB  conda-forge
    parso-0.5.1                |             py_0          65 KB  conda-forge
    pcre-8.43                  |       he1b5a44_0         257 KB  conda-forge
    pexpect-4.7.0              |           py37_0          78 KB  conda-forge
    pickleshare-0.7.5          |        py37_1000          12 KB  conda-forge
    pip-19.3.1                 |           py37_0         1.9 MB  conda-forge
    prometheus_client-0.7.1    |             py_0          38 KB  conda-forge
    prompt_toolkit-2.0.10      |             py_0         221 KB  conda-forge
    protobuf-3.11.1            |   py37he1b5a44_0         697 KB  conda-forge
    pthread-stubs-0.4          |    h14c3975_1001           5 KB  conda-forge
    ptyprocess-0.6.0           |          py_1001          15 KB  conda-forge
    pygments-2.5.2             |             py_0         669 KB  conda-forge
    pygpu-0.7.6                |py37hc1659b7_1000         680 KB  conda-forge
    pyparsing-2.4.5            |             py_0          58 KB  conda-forge
    pyqt-5.9.2                 |   py37hcca6a23_4         5.7 MB  conda-forge
    pyrsistent-0.15.6          |   py37h516909a_0          89 KB  conda-forge
    python-3.7.3               |       h357f687_2        35.3 MB  conda-forge
    python-dateutil-2.8.1      |             py_0         220 KB  conda-forge
    pytz-2019.3                |             py_0         237 KB  conda-forge
    pyyaml-5.2                 |   py37h516909a_0         184 KB  conda-forge
    pyzmq-18.1.1               |   py37h1768529_0         517 KB  conda-forge
    qt-5.9.7                   |       h52cfd70_2        85.9 MB  conda-forge
    qtconsole-4.6.0            |             py_0          90 KB  conda-forge
    readline-8.0               |       hf8c457e_0         441 KB  conda-forge
    send2trash-1.5.0           |             py_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    setuptools-42.0.2          |           py37_0         636 KB  conda-forge
    sip-4.19.8                 |py37hf484d3e_1000         290 KB  conda-forge
    six-1.13.0                 |           py37_0          22 KB  conda-forge
    sqlite-3.30.1              |       hcee41ef_0         2.0 MB  conda-forge
    tensorboard-1.13.1         |           py37_0         3.3 MB  conda-forge
    tensorflow-1.13.1          |   py37h90a7d86_1        75.5 MB  conda-forge
    tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0|             py_0         205 KB
    termcolor-1.1.0            |             py_2           6 KB  conda-forge
    terminado-0.8.3            |           py37_0          23 KB  conda-forge
    testpath-0.4.4             |             py_0          85 KB  conda-forge
    theano-1.0.4               |py37hf484d3e_1000         3.6 MB  conda-forge
    tk-8.6.10                  |       hed695b0_0         3.2 MB  conda-forge
    tornado-6.0.3              |   py37h516909a_0         637 KB  conda-forge
    traitlets-4.3.3            |           py37_0         133 KB  conda-forge
    wcwidth-0.1.7              |             py_1          17 KB  conda-forge
    webencodings-0.5.1         |             py_1          12 KB  conda-forge
    werkzeug-0.16.0            |             py_0         259 KB  conda-forge
    wheel-0.33.6               |           py37_0          35 KB  conda-forge
    widgetsnbextension-3.5.1   |           py37_0         1.8 MB  conda-forge
    xorg-libxau-1.0.9          |       h14c3975_0          13 KB  conda-forge
    xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3        |       h516909a_0          18 KB  conda-forge
    xz-5.2.4                   |    h14c3975_1001         366 KB  conda-forge
    yaml-0.2.2                 |       h516909a_1          82 KB  conda-forge
    zeromq-4.3.2               |       he1b5a44_2         668 KB  conda-forge
    zipp-0.6.0                 |             py_0           7 KB  conda-forge
    zlib-1.2.11                |    h516909a_1006         105 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       429.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  binutils_impl_lin~ conda-forge/linux-64::binutils_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-he1b5a44_7
  binutils_linux-64  conda-forge/linux-64::binutils_linux-64-2.33.1-h9595d00_15
  bzip2              conda-forge/linux-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h516909a_2
  gcc_impl_linux-64  conda-forge/linux-64::gcc_impl_linux-64-7.3.0-habb00fd_2
  gcc_linux-64       conda-forge/linux-64::gcc_linux-64-7.3.0-h553295d_15
  gettext            conda-forge/linux-64::gettext-0.19.8.1-hc5be6a0_1002
  gxx_impl_linux-64  conda-forge/linux-64::gxx_impl_linux-64-7.3.0-hdf63c60_2
  gxx_linux-64       conda-forge/linux-64::gxx_linux-64-7.3.0-h553295d_15
  ld_impl_linux-64   conda-forge/linux-64::ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h53a641e_7
  libgpuarray        conda-forge/linux-64::libgpuarray-0.7.6-h14c3975_1003
  libiconv           conda-forge/linux-64::libiconv-1.15-h516909a_1005
  mako               conda-forge/noarch::mako-1.1.0-py_0
  mock               conda-forge/linux-64::mock-3.0.5-py37_0
  pthread-stubs      conda-forge/linux-64::pthread-stubs-0.4-h14c3975_1001
  pygpu              conda-forge/linux-64::pygpu-0.7.6-py37hc1659b7_1000
  theano             conda-forge/linux-64::theano-1.0.4-py37hf484d3e_1000
  xorg-libxau        conda-forge/linux-64::xorg-libxau-1.0.9-h14c3975_0
  xorg-libxdmcp      conda-forge/linux-64::xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h516909a_0

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  _tflow_select-2.3.0-mkl
  gmp-6.1.2-h6c8ec71_1
  google-pasta-0.1.8-py_0
  keras-base-2.2.4-py37_0
  libedit-3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0
  opt_einsum-3.1.0-py_0
  tensorflow-base-1.15.0-mkl_py37he1670d9_0
  wrapt-1.11.2-py37h7b6447c_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.11.27~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0
  cycler             pkgs/main/linux-64::cycler-0.10.0-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::cycler-0.10.0-py_2
  entrypoints             pkgs/main::entrypoints-0.3-py37_0 --> conda-forge::entrypoints-0.3-py37_1000
  fontconfig         pkgs/main::fontconfig-2.13.0-h9420a91~ --> conda-forge::fontconfig-2.13.1-he4413a7_1000
  freetype             pkgs/main::freetype-2.9.1-h8a8886c_1 --> conda-forge::freetype-2.10.0-he983fc9_1
  gast                pkgs/main/linux-64::gast-0.2.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::gast-0.3.2-py_0
  grpcio             pkgs/main::grpcio-1.16.1-py37hf8bcb03~ --> conda-forge::grpcio-1.23.0-py37he9ae1f9_0
  gst-plugins-base   pkgs/main::gst-plugins-base-1.14.0-hb~ --> conda-forge::gst-plugins-base-1.14.5-h0935bb2_0
  gstreamer          pkgs/main::gstreamer-1.14.0-hb453b48_1 --> conda-forge::gstreamer-1.14.5-h36ae1b5_0
  h5py                 pkgs/main::h5py-2.9.0-py37h7918eee_0 --> conda-forge::h5py-2.10.0-nompi_py37h513d04c_100
  hdf5                    pkgs/main::hdf5-1.10.4-hb1b8bf9_0 --> conda-forge::hdf5-1.10.5-nompi_h3c11f04_1104
  icu                        pkgs/main::icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1 --> conda-forge::icu-58.2-hf484d3e_1000
  ipython_genutils   pkgs/main/linux-64::ipython_genutils-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py_1
  jpeg                        pkgs/main::jpeg-9b-h024ee3a_2 --> conda-forge::jpeg-9c-h14c3975_1001
  jupyter_console    pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyter_console-5~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_console-6.0.0-py_0
  keras                            pkgs/main::keras-2.2.4-0 --> conda-forge::keras-2.3.1-py37_0
  keras-applications pkgs/main::keras-applications-1.0.8-p~ --> conda-forge::keras-applications-1.0.8-py_1
  libffi                 pkgs/main::libffi-3.2.1-hd88cf55_4 --> conda-forge::libffi-3.2.1-he1b5a44_1006
  libgcc-ng           pkgs/main::libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0 --> conda-forge::libgcc-ng-9.2.0-hdf63c60_0
  libgfortran-ng     pkgs/main::libgfortran-ng-7.3.0-hdf63~ --> conda-forge::libgfortran-ng-7.3.0-hdf63c60_2
  libprotobuf        pkgs/main::libprotobuf-3.10.1-hd40887~ --> conda-forge::libprotobuf-3.11.1-h8b12597_0
  libsodium          pkgs/main::libsodium-1.0.16-h1bed415_0 --> conda-forge::libsodium-1.0.17-h516909a_0
  libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main::libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c6~ --> conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0-hdf63c60_0
  libuuid               pkgs/main::libuuid-1.0.3-h1bed415_2 --> conda-forge::libuuid-2.32.1-h14c3975_1000
  libxcb                  pkgs/main::libxcb-1.13-h1bed415_1 --> conda-forge::libxcb-1.13-h14c3975_1002
  libxml2               pkgs/main::libxml2-2.9.9-hea5a465_1 --> conda-forge::libxml2-2.9.9-h13577e0_2
  mistune            pkgs/main::mistune-0.8.4-py37h7b6447c~ --> conda-forge::mistune-0.8.4-py37h516909a_1000
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main::mkl_fft-1.0.15-py37ha843d7~ --> conda-forge::mkl_fft-1.0.15-py37h516909a_1
  more-itertools     pkgs/main/linux-64::more-itertools-7.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::more-itertools-8.0.2-py_0
  nbformat           pkgs/main/linux-64::nbformat-4.4.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::nbformat-4.4.0-py_1
  ncurses                 pkgs/main::ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1 --> conda-forge::ncurses-6.1-hf484d3e_1002
  pandoc                        pkgs/main::pandoc-2.2.3.2-0 --> conda-forge::pandoc-2.8.1-0
  pickleshare           pkgs/main::pickleshare-0.7.5-py37_0 --> conda-forge::pickleshare-0.7.5-py37_1000
  protobuf           pkgs/main::protobuf-3.10.1-py37he6710~ --> conda-forge::protobuf-3.11.1-py37he1b5a44_0
  ptyprocess         pkgs/main/linux-64::ptyprocess-0.6.0-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::ptyprocess-0.6.0-py_1001
  pyqt                 pkgs/main::pyqt-5.9.2-py37h05f1152_2 --> conda-forge::pyqt-5.9.2-py37hcca6a23_4
  pyyaml             pkgs/main::pyyaml-5.1.2-py37h7b6447c_0 --> conda-forge::pyyaml-5.2-py37h516909a_0
  pyzmq              pkgs/main::pyzmq-18.1.0-py37he6710b0_0 --> conda-forge::pyzmq-18.1.1-py37h1768529_0
  qt                         pkgs/main::qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1 --> conda-forge::qt-5.9.7-h52cfd70_2
  readline               pkgs/main::readline-7.0-h7b6447c_5 --> conda-forge::readline-8.0-hf8c457e_0
  sip                  pkgs/main::sip-4.19.8-py37hf484d3e_0 --> conda-forge::sip-4.19.8-py37hf484d3e_1000
  termcolor          pkgs/main/linux-64::termcolor-1.1.0-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::termcolor-1.1.0-py_2
  tk                         pkgs/main::tk-8.6.8-hbc83047_0 --> conda-forge::tk-8.6.10-hed695b0_0
  wcwidth            pkgs/main/linux-64::wcwidth-0.1.7-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::wcwidth-0.1.7-py_1
  xz                         pkgs/main::xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_4 --> conda-forge::xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_1001
  yaml                     pkgs/main::yaml-0.1.7-had09818_2 --> conda-forge::yaml-0.2.2-h516909a_1
  zeromq                 pkgs/main::zeromq-4.3.1-he6710b0_3 --> conda-forge::zeromq-4.3.2-he1b5a44_2
  zlib                    pkgs/main::zlib-1.2.11-h7b6447c_3 --> conda-forge::zlib-1.2.11-h516909a_1006

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  _libgcc_mutex                                   pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  absl-py                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  astor              pkgs/main/linux-64::astor-0.8.0-py37_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::astor-0.7.1-py_0
  attrs                                           pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  backcall           pkgs/main/linux-64::backcall-0.1.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::backcall-0.1.0-py_0
  bleach             pkgs/main/linux-64::bleach-3.1.0-py37~ --> conda-forge/noarch::bleach-3.1.0-py_0
  c-ares             pkgs/main::c-ares-1.15.0-h7b6447c_1001 --> conda-forge::c-ares-1.15.0-h516909a_1001
  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  dbus                   pkgs/main::dbus-1.13.12-h746ee38_0 --> conda-forge::dbus-1.13.6-he372182_0
  decorator                                       pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  defusedxml                                      pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  expat                   pkgs/main::expat-2.2.6-he6710b0_0 --> conda-forge::expat-2.2.5-he1b5a44_1004
  glib                    pkgs/main::glib-2.63.1-h5a9c865_0 --> conda-forge::glib-2.58.3-py37h6f030ca_1002
  importlib_metadata                              pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  ipykernel          pkgs/main::ipykernel-5.1.3-py37h39e3c~ --> conda-forge::ipykernel-5.1.3-py37h5ca1d4c_0
  ipython            pkgs/main::ipython-7.10.1-py37h39e3ca~ --> conda-forge::ipython-7.10.1-py37h5ca1d4c_0
  ipywidgets                                      pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  jedi                                            pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  jinja2                                          pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  joblib                                          pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  jsonschema                                      pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  jupyter_client     pkgs/main::jupyter_client-5.3.4-py37_0 --> conda-forge::jupyter_client-5.3.3-py37_1
  jupyter_core                                    pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  keras-preprocessi~ pkgs/main::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-~ --> conda-forge::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-py_0
  kiwisolver         pkgs/main::kiwisolver-1.1.0-py37he671~ --> conda-forge::kiwisolver-1.1.0-py37hc9558a2_0
  libpng                pkgs/main::libpng-1.6.37-hbc83047_0 --> conda-forge::libpng-1.6.37-hed695b0_0
  markdown           pkgs/main/linux-64::markdown-3.1.1-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::markdown-3.1.1-py_0
  markupsafe         pkgs/main::markupsafe-1.1.1-py37h7b64~ --> conda-forge::markupsafe-1.1.1-py37h516909a_0
  mkl-service        pkgs/main::mkl-service-2.3.0-py37he90~ --> conda-forge::mkl-service-2.3.0-py37h516909a_0
  mkl_random         pkgs/main::mkl_random-1.1.0-py37hd6b4~ --> conda-forge::mkl_random-1.1.0-py37hb3f55d8_0
  nbconvert                                       pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  notebook                 pkgs/main::notebook-6.0.2-py37_0 --> conda-forge::notebook-6.0.1-py37_0
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_3 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-h516909a_0
  pandocfilters      pkgs/main/linux-64::pandocfilters-1.4~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pandocfilters-1.4.2-py_1
  parso                                           pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  pcre                      pkgs/main::pcre-8.43-he6710b0_0 --> conda-forge::pcre-8.43-he1b5a44_0
  pexpect                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  pip                                             pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  prometheus_client                               pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  prompt_toolkit       pkgs/main::prompt_toolkit-3.0.2-py_0 --> conda-forge::prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py_0
  pygments                                        pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  pyparsing                                       pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  pyrsistent         pkgs/main::pyrsistent-0.15.6-py37h7b6~ --> conda-forge::pyrsistent-0.15.6-py37h516909a_0
  python                 pkgs/main::python-3.7.5-h0371630_0 --> conda-forge::python-3.7.3-h357f687_2
  python-dateutil                                 pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  pytz                                            pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  qtconsole                                       pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  send2trash         pkgs/main/linux-64::send2trash-1.5.0-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::send2trash-1.5.0-py_0
  setuptools                                      pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  six                                             pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  sqlite                pkgs/main::sqlite-3.30.1-h7b6447c_0 --> conda-forge::sqlite-3.30.1-hcee41ef_0
  tensorboard        pkgs/main/noarch::tensorboard-1.15.0-~ --> conda-forge/linux-64::tensorboard-1.13.1-py37_0
  tensorflow         pkgs/main::tensorflow-1.15.0-mkl_py37~ --> conda-forge::tensorflow-1.13.1-py37h90a7d86_1
  terminado                                       pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  testpath                                        pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  tornado            pkgs/main::tornado-6.0.3-py37h7b6447c~ --> conda-forge::tornado-6.0.3-py37h516909a_0
  traitlets                                       pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  webencodings       pkgs/main/linux-64::webencodings-0.5.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::webencodings-0.5.1-py_1
  werkzeug                                        pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  wheel                                           pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  widgetsnbextension                              pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  zipp                                            pkgs/main --> conda-forge

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  tensorflow-estima~                    1.15.1-pyh2649769_0 --> 1.13.0-py_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.

(myenv) [myname@ourserver ~]$ conda create --name myenv2 --clone myenv
Source:      /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv
Destination: /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv2
Packages: 130
Files: 5
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate myenv2
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(myenv) [myname@ourserver ~]$ conda activate myenv2
(myenv2) [myname@ourserver ~]$ conda upgrade -c conda-forge keras
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv2

  added / updated specs:
    - keras


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    binutils_impl_linux-64-2.33.1|       he1b5a44_7         8.6 MB  conda-forge
    binutils_linux-64-2.33.1   |      h9595d00_15          21 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2019.11.28 |       hecc5488_0         145 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py37_0         148 KB  conda-forge
    gcc_impl_linux-64-7.3.0    |       habb00fd_2        70.5 MB  conda-forge
    gcc_linux-64-7.3.0         |      h553295d_15          22 KB  conda-forge
    gxx_impl_linux-64-7.3.0    |       hdf63c60_2        19.1 MB  conda-forge
    gxx_linux-64-7.3.0         |      h553295d_15          21 KB  conda-forge
    keras-2.2.4                |           py37_1         492 KB  conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1    |       h53a641e_7         653 KB  conda-forge
    libgpuarray-0.7.6          |    h14c3975_1003         263 KB  conda-forge
    mako-1.1.0                 |             py_0          57 KB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.1.1d             |       h516909a_0         2.1 MB  conda-forge
    pygpu-0.7.6                |py37hc1659b7_1000         680 KB  conda-forge
    theano-1.0.4               |py37hf484d3e_1000         3.6 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       106.3 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  binutils_impl_lin~ conda-forge/linux-64::binutils_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-he1b5a44_7
  binutils_linux-64  conda-forge/linux-64::binutils_linux-64-2.33.1-h9595d00_15
  gcc_impl_linux-64  conda-forge/linux-64::gcc_impl_linux-64-7.3.0-habb00fd_2
  gcc_linux-64       conda-forge/linux-64::gcc_linux-64-7.3.0-h553295d_15
  gxx_impl_linux-64  conda-forge/linux-64::gxx_impl_linux-64-7.3.0-hdf63c60_2
  gxx_linux-64       conda-forge/linux-64::gxx_linux-64-7.3.0-h553295d_15
  ld_impl_linux-64   conda-forge/linux-64::ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h53a641e_7
  libgpuarray        conda-forge/linux-64::libgpuarray-0.7.6-h14c3975_1003
  mako               conda-forge/noarch::mako-1.1.0-py_0
  pygpu              conda-forge/linux-64::pygpu-0.7.6-py37hc1659b7_1000
  theano             conda-forge/linux-64::theano-1.0.4-py37hf484d3e_1000

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.11.27~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0
  keras                            pkgs/main::keras-2.2.4-0 --> conda-forge::keras-2.2.4-py37_1

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_3 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-h516909a_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

Comment: I'd file on [Conda's GitHub Issues](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues). I think v4.7 introduced some changes to solving that have many kinks that need to be worked out.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9535